# Kafka consumer not really acknowledge although used MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have an app using Spring Boot 2.5.2

We have a kafka consumer and it's running in some instance of applications.
Here is the Consumer Config

```
@Bean("KafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(isBatchConsumer);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(messageProcessorExecutor());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, messagingAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxBatch);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_ISOLATION_LEVEL, IsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeoutKafkaConfig);
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,
            CooperativeStickyAssignor.class.getName());
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

Here is my Consumer

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${topic.mesage}", groupId = "#{'${groupid.ms}'}", properties = {
        "key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"}, concurrency = "${messaging.consumer.concurrent.thread}", containerFactory = "KafkaListenerContainerFactory")
 public void consumerListener(String data, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Integer partitions,
                                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offsets) {
    logger.info("MessagingConsumer partitions {} offsets {}", partitions, offsets);
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    logger.info("MessagingConsumer acknowledge: " + data);
 ...
```

When I redeploy my application, an error occur. I found a request has been duplicated consume.
In the first instance, we found 2 logs show that the message has been ack ("MessagingConsumer partitions 29 offsets 21204" and "MessagingConsumer acknowledge:")  . But after sometime, the messsage has been consume again in second instance with same partition and offset. between that log of 2 instance, I found some "partitions revoked:" and "partitions assigned:".

But I cannot understand why if I has ack sucessfully , why the message still consume twice.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Kafka consumers aren't guaranteed to be exactly once, by default

Comment: Is there a way to be sure that a message has been committed?

Comment: That'd be from the producer's ack

Comment: I known about producer, but in case off consume messsage, we just choose MANUAL_IMMEDIATE ack mode. As I understand, that mean the message will be ack sync  and wait the response. There are no errror occur so I dont know why the ack sync still fail. And is the anyway to ensure a consume message has been ack ?