# Records are getting re-delivered with manual ack ( AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE)

Tags: spring-kafka

Is it possible that record will redeliver again once it is properly ack?  Sometime we are getting same record multiple time.
Attached image https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yC1M.jpg. Can see in image, multiple service receive same record at different time

I can't able to reproduce this in local machine.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.sample.topic}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment ack) {
        

        //Ack record
        sendAck(ack);
        
    }


private void sendAck(Acknowledgment ack) {
        try {
            ack.acknowledge();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred while sending ack");
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
```

```
@Bean
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(10));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);

    return factory;
}
```

```
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        
        Map<String, Object> consumerPropsMap = new HashMap<>();
        
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommitConfig);
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, autoCommitConfigIntervalMs);
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupIdConfig);
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
        
        consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor");
        
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(heartbeatIntervalMs)){
            consumerPropsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, heartbeatIntervalMs);     
         } 
        
        
        return consumerPropsMap;
}
```

Comment: It can happen if a forced rebalance occurs, causing the ack to fail. Such a rebalance can happen if the listener takes too long to process the records received by a `poll()`.

Comment: Hi Gary, that's correct, if rebalance occur, then ack.acknowledge() should fail. but it's not happening in environment.  I checked logs also , 1st record processing took few millisecond to process completely and there was no trace of exception log[ logger.error("Exception occurred while sending ack") ]. This record was properly acknowledged and same consumer thread picked another record. I tried to produces this issue in local m/c by abruptly killing one service instance or forcing consumer rebalance, but it working fine as expected (exception occur during ack). is there may any other reason?

Comment: I cannot think of any other scenario, unless you are processing the records asynchronously and acknowledging records out of order. There is a new feature in 2.8 to support (defer) out of order commits.

Comment: This is happening when rebalancing happen and the consumer thread assign to different partition but after some time same consumer thread again assign to older partition ( Initially conumer-thread-c-1 initially assign to partition 10 but after rebalancing assign to partition 15 and again after some time assign to partition 10 ). Due to which all the record processed by new consumer thread of partition 10 (assigned after rebalancing) are again process by this consumer thread (conumer-thread-c-1).

Comment: I found this question similar to mine. I am using spring kafka 2.5.2 version  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893807/kafka-consumer-not-really-acknowledge-although-used-manual-immediate .

Comment: You must be doing something wrong; provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the behavior you are seeing.